Dequeued item exists but std::counting_semaphore::try_acquire() fails in single-consumer MPSC queue
I have a single-consumer, multiple-producer lock-free queue (MPSCQueue) combined with a std::counting_semaphore to notify the consumer when new items are enqueued. The consumer uses dequeue() to attempt fetching an item; if it succeeds, it calls sema.try_acquire() which I expect to succeed every time there’s actually an item in the queue. However, under very rare circumstances, I get an assertion failure indicating try_acquire() returned false even though the queue returned a valid item.
I can confirm there is truly only one consumer thread. There are no other places calling dequeue(). The code uses std::memory_order_seq_cst for atomic operations in the queue, and sema.release()/sema.acquire() for the semaphore.
Why might this happen?
It seems like a memory ordering or visibility issue where the consumer sees the newly linked node in the queue before it sees the corresponding release() operation on the semaphore. But I thought seq_cst plus semaphore release/acquire would be enough to guarantee proper ordering. Any ideas or clarifications on how to ensure we never see a valid item in the queue but still fail try_acquire()?
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <semaphore>

template <typename T>
class MPSCQueue {
  struct Node {
    T data;
    std::atomic<Node*> next;

    // Default constructor for the dummy node
    Node() : next(nullptr) {}
    // Constructor that moves the data in
    Node(T data_) : data(std::move(data_)), next(nullptr) {}
  };

  // Atomic head pointer for multiple producers
  std::atomic<Node*> head;
  // Tail pointer for the single consumer
  Node* tail;

 public:
  std::atomic_size_t enqueue_count = 0;
  size_t dequeue_count = 0;

  MPSCQueue() {
    Node* dummy = new Node();
    head.store(dummy, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    tail = dummy;
  }

  ~MPSCQueue() {
    Node* node = tail;
    while (node) {
      Node* next = node->next.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
      delete node;
      node = next;
    }
  }

  // Called by producers
  void enqueue(T data) {
    enqueue_count.fetch_add(1);
    Node* node = new Node(std::move(data));
    // Swap in the new node as the head
    Node* prev_head = head.exchange(node, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    // Link the old head to the new node
    prev_head->next.store(node, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
  }

  // Called by the single consumer
  std::optional<T> dequeue() {
    // Check the next pointer of the tail
    Node* next = tail->next.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    if (next) {
      // Move the data out
      T res = std::move(next->data);
      delete tail;
      tail = next;
      dequeue_count += 1;
      return res;
    }
    return std::nullopt;
  }

  size_t size() { return enqueue_count.load() - dequeue_count; }
};

template <typename T>
class MPSCQueueConsumerLock {
  MPSCQueue<T> queue;
  std::counting_semaphore<> sema{0};

 public:
  void enqueue(T data) {
    queue.enqueue(std::move(data));
    // Release the semaphore to notify the consumer
    sema.release();
  }

  // Single consumer calls this
  T dequeue() {
    auto re = queue.dequeue();
    if (re.has_value()) {
      // We have an item, so we expect the semaphore count to be > 0
      if (!sema.try_acquire()) {
        // Unexpectedly fails in rare cases
        std::cerr << __FILE__ << ":" << __FUNCTION__
                  << " sema.try_acquire() should succeed, please check\n";
        assert(false);
      }
      return re.value();
    }
    // Otherwise, block until something is available
    sema.acquire();
    return queue.dequeue().value();
  }

  size_t size() { return queue.size(); }
};

Symptom
Sometimes (very low probability, but still possible) the code hits:
/path/to/mpsc.hpp:dequeue sema try_acquire should be success, please check
python: /path/to/mpsc.hpp:79: T MPSCQueueConsumerLock<T>::dequeue() [...]
Assertion `false' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

I have verified there is truly only one consumer thread and this is the only place where dequeue() is called.
Question:
How could it happen that the consumer can see the new node in MPSCQueue, but the corresponding sema.release() call is not observed (so try_acquire() fails)?
Is there a subtlety in std::counting_semaphore or the memory ordering that I’m missing?
Any suggestions to ensure the consumer’s view of the queue and the semaphore’s count stay consistent?
Additional

I used std::memory_order_seq_cst for all the atomic operations in the queue.
The consumer is strictly single-threaded; no other threads call dequeue().
Could there be a hidden memory fence issue between exchange(..., seq_cst) and sema.release()?

Any pointers or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You have a race condition in your check.
void enqueue(T data) {
    queue.enqueue(std::move(data));
    // thread suspended by OS here
    sema.release();
  }

T dequeue() {
    auto re = queue.dequeue();
    if (re.has_value()) {
      // thread gets an item while the other thread is suspended
      // semaphore not incremented yet !
      if (!sema.try_acquire()) {
        ...
  }

If you have 2 atomic operations A and B, and A happens before B, if B is visible then A is visible, however seeing A visible doesn't infer anything on B, you need to decrement the semaphore before you dequeue.
T dequeue() {
    sema.acquire();
    return queue.dequeue().value();
  }


Thank you, I understand this. I change this if to while to make sure it decrease 1 sema.
