How to implement a custom mutex with multiple lock-unlock method?
I'd like to implement a custom mutex different from std::mutex.
I want it have these methods:

lock() : locks a mutex just like std::mutex, may have system calls, make the caller give up its CPU and cause context switching.
spinlock(): locks a mutex without system calls, caller don't give up its CPU and cause context switching.
try_lock(): tries to lock and returns whether it's succeeded.
unlock(): unlocks this mutex no matter it's locked by lock() or spinlock()

If these methods could be implemented, I can write these codes that I think may have better performance.
custom_mutex cm; //declaration

void producer(){
   cm.spinlock();  //the producer section has extremely less contention, so I use spinlock().
   //producer works...
}

void consumer(){
   cm.lock();      //the consumer section consumes quickly and waits a lot, so lock() is better.
    //consumer works...

}

Also, I have questions about std::mutex::try_lock, when I use "while(!std::mutex::try_lock())" it's just like spinlock, what's the difference between testing std::mutex::try_lock in a loop and using a custom implemented spinlock?
In fact I'm trying to implement a logger. It's a multiple producer single consumer model, using a MPSC queue. Say a program has threads with codes logging messages, which produce print requests to the logger thread, and the logger thread must print messages the queue contained and pop almost immediately. I want producers spend as less time as possible so I want the queue for producers is lock-free (using atomic int),not fall into any context switching and system calls. Also, the logger thread shouldn't be busy-waiting so there's a condition variable or semaphore needed.
But std::mutex the condition variable used to synchronize is costly for producers when producers use it to set flags to wake up the consumer. Since producers don't want to be swapped out the CPU for just committing a logging request, I really want it to be lock-free.(using spinlock to protect variables related to the condition variable)
And for the logger thread I want to use std::mutex with condition variable to avoid busy-waiting.
So the scenario is like:
class Logger{
   Lock_Free_Queue q;
   condition_variable cv;
   custom_mutex lok;   // mutex that I'd like to implement
   int count=0;

   void commit_msg(string msg){
      q.push(msg);  //thread safe guaranteed by lock free method (using atomic int, etc..)
      lok.spinlock();  //avoid context switching and system calls, will be unblocked very soon
      count++;         //assuming that q.empty() can't use as a flag of consumable product, so 'int count' is used.
      lok.unlock();
      cv.notify_all(); // wake up logger thread
   }

   void logger_thread(){
      lok.lock();  // logger thread isn't sensitive to context switching and waits for most of the time.
      while(count<=0){
          lok.unlock();
          cv.wait();
          lok.lock();
      }
      count--;
      lok.unlock();
      //other works
   }

}
Logger logger;

void producer(){
    ....
    logger.commit_msg("texts..."); 
   // message is pushed into a MPSC queue maintained by logger, then logger thread is waken up.
    ....
}


most modern mutexes (including std::mutex) are spinlocks for a little while before joining the wait queue ...

you are looking for a lock-free MPSC queue, a spin-locked one is still not lock-free, it may even be worse than std::mutex under high load.

fyi i have just seen a lock-free MPSC queue a few days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79309192/dequeued-item-exists-but-stdcounting-semaphoretry-acquire-fails-in-single/79309365#79309365 , but FWIW i'd probably use an off-the-shelf one as writing safe multithreaded code is hard.

the best queue that comes to mind for this is onetbb concurrentQueue, it is header-only although the library contains other parts that are not header-only.

Spinning is easy, but spinning well requires CPU-specific code like x86 _mm_pause().  See Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly .  To sleep in the non-spinlock version, you want .wait.  But then unlock has to figure out when to .notify_one

Related: What would it take to implement a mutex using std::atomic? (adding a try-lock should be trivial; just like a spinlock that never has a fallback to sleep/wake) / Can std::atomic::wait be used to replace the mutex? / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72889201/c20-mutex-with-atomic-wait

I really want it to be lock-free - A lock-free lock is a contradiction.  See the definitions in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm - if at any point in your program, one thread sleeping forever would prevent others from making progress (e.g. while that thread holds a lock), your algorithm isn't lock-free.  Sleeping vs. spinning when progress is blocked is an engineering tuning choice for non-lock-free algorithms.  If your logging system was actually lock-free (at least in the common case), it would always make sense to keep trying because the next attempt could succeed.

(Some things are very hard to make lock-free or non-blocking, and doing so can make the uncontended case slower or require sacrifices in stuff like how you allocate memory.  Just make sure you're using the right terminology when telling people about what you want.)

"I can write these codes that I think may have better performance" - The key point there is that you think that may have better performance, but have you made actual measurements / profiled the code to prove that it performs better? Often times, what we think may be better actually turns out to be the same or worse. Always measure.
